# Accessing single object in nested array when mapping over array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Sorry for the confusing title!

This is a small chunk of the array that I am mapping over in React:

```
var listOfProductsToShow = [{
    "markets": [{
        "date": "2017-10-25",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWsDKs584lSNbhN1t",
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-10-31",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWtWatedeIHOZZ1Dk",
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-11-04",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWuWq1c22V2NBh12q",
      },
    ],
    "price": "9.99",
    "product": "Chicken Wings",
    "uid": "-KyRAxDoma3vwKXCiNBU",
    "unit": "lb",
    "vendorName": "Bob's Beef",
  },
  {
    "markets": [{
        "date": "2017-10-25",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWsDKs584lSNbhN1t",
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-10-31",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWtWatedeIHOZZ1Dk",
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-11-04",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWuWq1c22V2NBh12q",
      },
    ],
    "price": "9.99",
    "product": "Burgers",
    "uid": "-Kyax36Yo0Nr2fm01mgL",
    "unit": "lb",
    "vendorName": "Bob's Beef",
  }
];
```

For each Object I am trying to access the markets array and within that just the first "market" field. I tried the following below but get an error.

```
{listOfProductsToShow.map((product, idx) => (
  product.markets[0].market
))}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? I know I can map over the markets array but I only want the first market name. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That last snippet looks about right to me. You said it gives you an error? Which error specifically?

Comment: undefined is not object (evaluating 'product.markets[0].market')

Comment: how consistent is your data? Is `markets` always an array? Is that array ever empty?

Comment: yes it does always have something there. I actually got it to work in jsfiddle but not in react. any idea why that might be? 
js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/e0Ln6noj/

Comment: The code may be executed before a request for `listOfProductsToShow ` resolves. The code you have posted here is valid, so the only cause would be the data being a shape you are not anticipating. Put a `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listOfProductsToShow)))` above your snippet and make sure it is valid each time the snippet is executed. It may be empty if the code runs before a network request resolves.

Comment: also, can you hardcode the sample data in your application and map over the hardcoded data?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the data is there because all the fields are rendering just fine. When I do this :   listOfProductsToShow.map((product, idx) => (
   console.log(product.markets[0])
  ))

i get undefined for all of them but when I console.log(product.markets) I get the correct output (array of objects)

Comment: Try using a debugging tool like chrome dev tools to step through your code - there is nothing more people here can do to help without seeing your exact code since the error can't be reproduced outside your app. If you use a debugger, you can step through your call stack with excruciating detail and find where the data is getting mangled.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `markets` array is sometimes empty, causing the `undefined is not an object` error. You can get around this by checking for it's existence first, and returning undefined if it's not there. Then filter out all the undefined values at the end:

```js
var myArray = [
   {
    "markets":  [
       {
        "date": "2017-10-25",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWsDKs584lSNbhN1t",
      },
       {
        "date": "2017-10-31",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWtWatedeIHOZZ1Dk",
      },
       {
        "date": "2017-11-04",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWuWq1c22V2NBh12q",
      },
    ],
    "price": "9.99",
    "product": "Chicken Wings",
    "uid": "-KyRAxDoma3vwKXCiNBU",
    "unit": "lb",
    "vendorName": "Bob's Beef",
  },
   {
    "markets":  [
       {
        "date": "2017-10-25",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWsDKs584lSNbhN1t",
      },
       {
        "date": "2017-10-31",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWtWatedeIHOZZ1Dk",
      },
       {
        "date": "2017-11-04",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWuWq1c22V2NBh12q",
      },
    ],
    "price": "9.99",
    "product": "Burgers",
    "uid": "-Kyax36Yo0Nr2fm01mgL",
    "unit": "lb",
    "vendorName": "Bob's Beef",
  },
  {
    "markets": []
  }
];

console.log(myArray)

var result = myArray.map(x => x.markets[0] && x.markets[0].market).filter(Boolean)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array =  [
{
    "markets":  [
    {
        "date": "2017-10-25",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWsDKs584lSNbhN1t",
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-10-31",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWtWatedeIHOZZ1Dk",
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-11-04",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWuWq1c22V2NBh12q",
    },
    ],
    "price": "9.99",
    "product": "Chicken Wings",
    "uid": "-KyRAxDoma3vwKXCiNBU",
    "unit": "lb",
    "vendorName": "Bob's Beef",
},
{
    "markets":  [
    {
        "date": "2017-10-25",
        "market": "Tribeca1 Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWsDKs584lSNbhN1t",
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-10-31",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWtWatedeIHOZZ1Dk",
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-11-04",
        "market": "Tribeca Farmer's Market",
        "uid": "-KxcWuWq1c22V2NBh12q",
    },
    ],
    "price": "9.99",
    "product": "Burgers",
    "uid": "-Kyax36Yo0Nr2fm01mgL",
    "unit": "lb",
    "vendorName": "Bob's Beef",
},
];

let values = Object.values(array)
                .map( item => { return item.markets })
                .map( arrayIndexItem => arrayIndexItem.map( item2 => item2.market ) )
                .map( it => it[0] );
console.log(values);
```

Comment: this is one implementation not sure if you like it.

Comment: [
    ["2017-10-25", "2017-10-31", "2017-11-04"], 
    ["2017-10-25", "2017-10-31", "2017-11-04"]
    ]

Comment: oh you want market name..my bad, I think you got it from there based on my implementation and easy object access

Comment: thanks but I'm looking to get just the first market name - any ideas?

Comment: jsut use the answer above

Comment: I updated the answer so it will return the correct name for the market name 
the format is a position of the mapped items in two arrays you can extract the corresponding data by doing the outer arrays reference and [0].
Hope that helps. :)